# Javascript - How to find schedule Conflicts/overlaps in Events Array and create a new Array with the conflicting time windows

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, date

I am trying to figure out what's the most efficient way to do the following:

- I have an array of events objects, each object in the array has a start_time and end_time (Date) and an event_id.
- I need to parse each object in the array and identify if there's an overlap (start_time or end_time or both)
- I would like to generate a new array with:

  1. start_time + end_time of the conflicted time windows
  2. an array of Event id in conflict

  Note: more than 2 events can be overlapping
  Note2: let's assume the events are sorted ascendingly.

  For Example:

  ```
   function Event(id, startTime, endTime) {
    this.id = id;
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
  }

  function ConflictedTimeWindow(startTime, endTime, conflictedEventIds) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.conflictedEventIds = conflictedEventIds;
  }


  function Calendar() {
    //init empty event list
     this.eventList = [];
  }
  Calendar.prototype.schedule = function(event) {
      //add event to the event list
    this.eventList.push(event);
  }

  Calendar.prototype.findConflictedTimeWindows = function() {
      let conflictedWindows = [];
    // IMPLEMENT ME
   let sortedEvents = this.eventList.sort((previous, current)=> 
   previous.startTime - current.startTime);


     /* AFTER SORTING THE ARRAY I SHOULD LOOP (probably I need 2 loops??)
        on it and start identifying the overlaps and generate the new 
        array. SEE expected output in main() function   */
  }



  function main() {
    var calendar = new Calendar();
    console.log('calendar',calendar);
    calendar.schedule(new Event(1,
        new Date('2014-01-01 10:00'),
        new Date('2014-01-01 11:00')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(2,
        new Date('2014-01-01 11:00'),
        new Date('2014-01-01 12:00')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(3,
        new Date('2014-01-01 12:00'),
        new Date('2014-01-01 13:00')));

    calendar.schedule(new Event(4,
        new Date('2014-01-02 10:00'),
        new Date('2014-01-02 11:00')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(5,
        new Date('2014-01-02 09:30'),
        new Date('2014-01-02 11:30')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(6,
        new Date('2014-01-02 08:30'),
        new Date('2014-01-02 12:30')));

    calendar.schedule(new Event(7,
        new Date('2014-01-03 10:00'),
        new Date('2014-01-03 11:00')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(8,
        new Date('2014-01-03 09:30'),
        new Date('2014-01-03 10:30')));
    calendar.schedule(new Event(9,
        new Date('2014-01-03 09:45'),
        new Date('2014-01-03 10:45')));

        console.log(calendar.eventList);

    console.log(calendar.findConflictedTimeWindows());
    // SHOULD GIVE THE FOLLOWING OUTPUT

    // [{ start_time: "2014-01-02 09:30",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-02 10:00",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [5, 6] },
    //  { start_time: "2014-01-02 10:00",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-02 11:00",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [4, 5, 6] },
    //  { start_time: "2014-01-02 11:00",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-02 11:30",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [5, 6] },
    //  { start_time: "2014-01-03 09:45",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-03 10:00",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [8, 9] },
    //  { start_time: "2014-01-03 10:00",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-03 10:30",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [7, 8, 9] },
    //  { start_time: "2014-01-03 10:30",
    //    end_time: "2014-01-03 10:45",
    //    conflicted_event_ids: [7, 9] }]


    }

    main();

    var module = module || {};
    module.exports = { Calendar: Calendar, Event: Event, 
    ConflictedTimeWindow: ConflictedTimeWindow };
  ```

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Where is your `Calendar` constructor function?

Comment: You should find a better format for specifying dates, `new Date('2014-01-01 10:00')` is treated as an invalid date in Safari 10.

Comment: added calendar function. About the dates, I am aware of it, but not fundamental in this example :)

Comment: Replacing it with, say, `new Date(2014, 0, 2, 10)` would fix that issue.

Comment: Great Rob  I'll definitely do that, but what about the sorting algorithm? @RobG

Comment: To sort on start time you can use `this.eventList.sort((a, b) => a.startTime - b.startTime);` since array.prototype.sort sorts the original array. As for finding overlapping events, that's a bit of work. The event ID should be assigned by the Event constructor so you can enforce constraints like uniqueness and values. There should be an index for start and end times so you don't have to search the entire Event list every time, etc.

Comment: @RobG I have actually already sorted the array (see example), my problem is in the overlapping algorithm. The main issue I have is that I cannot change anything but the findConflictedTimeWindows and schedule function as this is an assignment in which I am not entitled to change neither the Event Constructor nor anything else. Any chance you guys can help me setting up a fiddle/codepen or similar?

Comment: @RobG replaced sorting with improved version (your example).